# read inputstream and use if statement to compare output

Tags: java

I want to read a data stream and everytime it reads a certain word or phrase I want the count to go up. The example I have below fails to count it. I tried looking for "echo percent" as well. All the bat file does is echo percent.

```
try { 
    String ls_str;
    String percent = "percent";
    Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\temp\\percenttest.bat"); 
    // get its output (your input) stream    
    DataInputStream ls_in = new DataInputStream(ls_proc.getInputStream()); 
    while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null ) { 
        System.out.println(ls_str);
        progressBar.setValue(progress);
        taskOutput.append(String.format(ls_str+"\n", progress));
        if (ls_str == percent)  {
            progress++;   
        } 
    }
} catch (IOException e1) { 
    System.out.println(e1.toString());                 
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
```

Comment: You need to use equals to compare strings: `if(ls_str.equals(percent))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: where is progress initialised?

Comment: Your use of `String.format` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare the Strings with `==`, use the `equals` method.

If you compare the Strings with `==`, you're checking to see if they're the same `String`.

If you compare them with `equals`, you're checking whether or not their contents are the same.

Instead of:

`if (ls_str == percent)`

Do this:

`if (ls_str.equals(percent))`

If you want to ignore case, you can do it like this:

`if (ls_str.equalsIgnoreCase(percent))`

---

**EDIT**

Your String format is also messed up.

Change:

`taskOutput.append(String.format(
        ls_str+"\n", progress));`

to:

`taskOutput.append(String.format(
        ls_str+"\n"), progress);`

Notice the parentheses change.

---

Take a look at these for more explanations:

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

Comment: ha! I knew that and forgot. Still kind of new to java, hard to keep it all down sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`DataInputStream.readLine` is deprecated. Use [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and its [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method or [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead. Also, use `.equals` to compare two strings, not `==`.

The `==` comparison only does a reference comparison, asking the question, "Are these two strings in the same place in memory?" Usually, the answer is "no." On the other hand, `equals` asks the question, "Are the characters in these two strings the same?" This is called deep comparison, and the `==` operator doesn't perform the deeper comparison.